# how to write argparse for jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, argparse

How can I write this `argparse` code in jupyter notebook?

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")

ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True,
    help="base path to YOLO directory")

ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")

ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3,
    help="threshold when applying non-maxima suppression")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Comment: I'm not sure jupyter notebooks are designed to interact with the command line arguments

Comment: command line arguments provided when starting the `jupyter` server are just for the server.  You can see them in the notebook with `sys.argv` but I don't think they'll be useful to you.  The server reads and uses that list.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute your jupyter notebook from command line and to pass arguments you can use tools like papermill 
The below github link has detailed documentation on how it can be used

https://github.com/nteract/papermill